# Xcode iOS UIAlert open different view than default

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

I have an app that can receive a push notification which is opened in a UIAlertView in the AppDelegate. The app will normally open to a tableview of items (if no push notification is present). Each item can be selected to view more detail about the item. How do I go about getting the detailed view to display with information from the push notification of an item? I saw this functionality in FaceBook Messenger where an incoming message launches the conversation from the specific user.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications can include embedded JSON, not just text, so you can put a small amount of command data into a push notification.

Here's some code that shows a message being passed in a push notification as well as an URL and a number that we only expect to see if the URL is there:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSString *url = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];

    if ([url length]) {

        NSNumber *fooCount = [userInfo objectForKey:@"Foo"];
```

You can now do whatever your app wants to do with this data.

Comment: I was looking more for the how-to aspect of having the app open directly into the detailed view rather than the table view based upon an id found in the JSON/push notification.